# bootstrap modal dialog backdrop in IE8

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

```
//INGNORE THE HTML ELEMENT
$("#myDialog").modal({ show: true,backdrop: "static", keyboard: false });
```

The top is my code. It can show modal dialog in IE8, but the shadow mask lost,it means I can click the link on the page when the dialog is open. IE9+, Firefox, Chrome can work well.

How can I solve this problem in IE8, THANKS!